# Can a NON-BRAHMIN be a teacher?

Tags: scripture, brahmins, varna, teaching

Were there any instances in itihasa shastra where non-brahmin were teacher?

Comment: Arjun was guru to Satyaki.

Comment: Possible, but very difficult and rare. Foremost example : Vishwamitra (former kshatriya).

Comment: Teacher is a generic term. In Hinduism we have guru acharya etc. Guru is someone who gives knowledge of Vedas. Nowadays the term Guru is used interchangeably with teacher. Guru has to be brahmin

Comment: Spiritual Guru (Diksha Guru) has to be a Brahmin only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On what grounds did RAmAnuja wished to accept KAnchipurNa as a guru?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22370/on-what-grounds-did-ramanuja-wished-to-accept-kanchipurna-as-a-guru)