# Did any Shankaracharya ever take a Shudra as a disciple?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, guru, shudra

Vyasatirtha had [Kanaka Dasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanaka_Dasa) as a disciple.

Ramanujacharya said to be [Kanchipurna's](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22370/on-what-grounds-did-ramanuja-wished-to-accept-kanchipurna-as-a-guru) disciple.

Did any *purva* Shankaracharya have a Shudra disciple?

Comment: Ādi Śaṅkarācārya probably did not, he is sort of not open about śūdras studying Vedic texts as can be seen in his commentary of Brahma Sūtras.